# phrasal verbs with reflexive pronouns

Tags: grammar, reflexive-pronouns

Is it correct to say "The alarm clock switches off itself"? Is it always "...switches itself off"?
Does the same happen with an intransitive verb like "wake up", that is, can we say "I always wake up myself"?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly idiomatic to use a phrase like:

> The kettle switches off itself

to mean that the kettle switches itself off. But it's likely that the speaker means **by itself**. It's a loose manner of speaking.

On the other hand **always wake up myself** would be puzzling. People might wonder whether you were simply emphasising that you always wake up, whether you wake yourself up or whether you mean wake up by yourself; that's to say, without anybody else beside you.

So I think that the answer would depend on the phrase concerned and on the context.